# Obfuscated DLL not loading via Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, obfuscation

I have an interface in my application, and several DLL's that extend it.  The interface provides one simple method :

```
public interface ICustomConversion
{
    string Namespace { get; }
    string Code { get; }

    int TotalCount { get; set; }
    int ErrorCount { get; set; }

    string ConvertList(string inputFileLocation);
}
```

The goal is to allow multiple files to be converted to our custom format.  I load up the DLL based on the user selection via reflection :

```
 var dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
 var type = dll.GetTypes().First();
 var instance = (ICustomConversion)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
 return instance.ConvertList(filename);
```

This all works great in the dev environment.  However, after obfuscation, it's unable to load the dll, and I'm not sure why.  Using ILSpy on the obfuscated DLL shows the method signature is still the same:

[image: ILSpy]

I'm curious what the issue is here.  Is reflection against the obfuscated assembly somehow breaking?  Has anyone else encountered this error before?  Thank you for any insight.

**UPDATE**

it looks like this line is throwing the exception:

```
var instance = (ICustomConversion)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: How is the obfuscation done ? If it's not performed, does the DLL load ?

Comment: Yes, sorry i meant to include that.  If I toss the unobfuscated DLL in, it works fine

Comment: I'd then say the obfuscator doesn't work

Comment: Is the .pdb file also present? Just wondering if ILSpy is also using that to help it view the right names

Comment: What type is returned by `dll.GetTypes().First();`? Try instead with `typeof(KnownType)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is just getting the first type declared by the DLL:

```
var type = dll.GetTypes().First();
```

This is not good practice. You should select a type based on some criteria.

Obfuscation may change the ordering of types in the assembly (perhaps due to name changes).

I recommend that you do this instead:

```
var type = dll.GetTypes().First(typeof(ICustomConversion).IsAssignableFrom);
```

That will select the first type that implements your interface.

Comment: You're totally right.  That fixed it.  Thank you much.